# Develop a web client app for app engine back end

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

This is a general question...

I have developed an android app with app engine and it is working great.

Problem is that not every one  has an android device..

Some one suggest that i should develop a web version  where by both android app and web app share the same back end.

I have zero experience in developing web apps..but i am a willing and competent learner.

So my question is that is it possible to have an android and web app share the same data stored in Google app engine BE?

Is there any online tutorials i can learn from? and what is the preferred technology to use for the web app?

Than you all in advance!

Ronald

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is that is it possible to have an android and web app
>   share the same data stored in Google app engine BE?

Yes. If the Android app consumes the backend API via REST, you simply can use the same approach for web. Take a look at [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) to know more about how to implement REST APIs in GAE. Also see the documentation on [how to consume endpoints from JavaScript clients](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js)

> Is there any online tutorials i can learn from? and what is the
>   preferred technology to use for the web app?

Tutorials depend on the frontend technology you are going to use. I personally prefer [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) because it makes you code Java and it compiles the client code into Javascript taking care of browsers compatibility. It has MVP, Ajax and well structured way to communicate with the server side code, bind controls to data. If you intend to use GWT, you can consume the API using the same Java client libraries generated for Android and make the calls to the API on server side code like a GWT RPC service for example. You can also use regular Servlets in GAE.

Comment: my android app actually use Google cloud end points. What you mean that i can say use the same approach with the web client app?. Let me start learning GWT. Thank you!

Comment: Great so you are on the right track already. I have modified my answer to make this point more clear :)

Comment: My Android app implements Endpoints for AppEngine according to the docs at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints#app-engine-java-endpoints-module-template which is an AsyncTask that connects with EndpointsApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null) . But none of the AsyncTask, AndroidHttp or AndroidJsonFactory classes are available in GWT. My desktop version connects with NetHttpTransport, JacksonFactory classes also unavailable to GWT. How do I generate the client? I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: @Matthew As far as I know Android studio does not support GWT or any real web framework .. it can only build static web projects .. I think you should use eclipse or IntelliJ ultimate. I will review how I did call endpoints from GWT and get back to you on that.

Comment: @M.Sameer I have my GWT project working OK (except for the Endpoints client) in Android Studio (which is a slight fork of IntelliJ IDEA). But if you can explain how to do it with Intellij IDEA (or Ultimate) I might be able to translate it to Android Studio. Thanks.